# Why the tapered optical fiber which dipcoated with rGO didnt give significant changes of voltage inside Photodetector?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, gas, fiber-optics, instrument

I already cut it carefully the jacket out from cladding, and then use ethanol to rub the cladding so the core can be dipcoated with PVA-rGO solution.

Now I can see higher voltage depends of how much concentration of rGO added to PVA and Aquades solution. The problem is, even though SmartSensor CO gas detector already rise to 800 ppm inside vacuum gas chamber (Already tried adding some air as well), still not giving any difference on Photodetector that connected to Multimeter. I also try again with Theremino Spectrometer (you can see on 2nd image) there is no wavelength changes. I already try to follow some journals that use multimode optical fiber. What should I do? Thank you.

[image: Webcam Spectrometer]